# Summing the values of an array in fortran 77

Tags: arrays, sum, subroutine, fortran77

I'm writing a program to minimise chi-squared for a four-parameter least squares fit. I've had a number of issues, but now the program keeps giving me the same three problems for my subroutine call-ins; 
"Assignment.f:12.25:

```
  REAL sum0,sum1,sum2,sumWt0,sumWt,sumWt2                           
                     1
```

Assignment.f:48.72:

```
  CALL sum2(sumWt2,Wt2)                                             
                                                                    2
```

Error: 'sum2' at (1) has a type, which is not consistent with the CALL at (2)"
The code is as follows:

```
      PROGRAM assignment

      ! A program designed to fit experiemental data, using the method
      ! of least squares to minimise the associated chi-squared and
      ! obtain the four control parameters A,B,h1 and h2.
      !*****************************************************************

      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER i,t0
      REAL t(17),t2(17),Ct(17),eCt(17),W(17),Wt0(17),Wt(17),Wt2(17)
      REAL A,B,h1,h2,Cs,matrix(2:2),inverse(2:2)
      REAL sum0,sum1,sum2,sumWt0,sumWt,sumWt2

      OPEN(21, FILE='data.txt', STATUS='OLD')
      DO i=1,17
         READ (21,*)t(i),Ct(i),eCt(i)
      END DO
      CLOSE(21)

      !*****************************************************************
      OPEN(21, FILE='outtest.txt', FORM='FORMATTED', STATUS='NEW')
      DO i=1,17
         WRITE(21,*)t(i),Ct(i),eCt(i)
      END DO
      CLOSE(21)

      !Just to check input file is being read correctly.
      !*****************************************************************


      DO i= 1,17,1

      t0= 1

      t2(i)= (t(i))**2
      W(i)= 1/(eCt(i))**2
      Wt0(i)= W(i)*t0
      Wt(i)= W(i)*t(i)
      Wt2(i)= W(i)*t2(i)

      !The above calculates Wt2, Wt and Wt0 for data.txt
      END DO

      CALL sum0(sumWt0,Wt0)
      WRITE(*,*) 'sumWt0=', sumWt0
      CALL sum1(sumWt,Wt)
      WRITE(*,*) 'sumWt=', sumWt
      CALL sum2(sumWt2,Wt2)
      WRITE(*,*) 'sumWt2=', sumWt2

      END

      !Assign weighted t values to the A matrix
      !*****************************************************************


      !*****************************************************************
      !****************************FUNCTIONS****************************
      !*****************************************************************

      !*****************************************************************
      REAL FUNCTION sum0(sumWt0,Wt0)
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER i,t0
      REAL sumWt0,Wt0(17),eCt(17),W(17)

      W(i)= 1/((eCt(i))**2)

      DO i= 1,17,1
      t0= 1

      Wt0(i)= W(i)*t0
      END DO


      SumWt0= 0.0
      DO 10 i=1,17
         sumWt0= sumWt0 + Wt0(i)
 10   CONTINUE

      RETURN
      END
      !Function used to sum weighted values of t^0
      !*****************************************************************


      !*****************************************************************
      DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION sum1(sumWt,Wt)
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER i, t(17)
      DOUBLE PRECISION sumWt,Wt(17),eCt(17),W(17)

      W(i)= 1/((eCt(i))**2)

      DO i= 1,17,1

      Wt(i)= W(i)*t(i)
      END DO


      SumWt= 0.0
      DO 10 i=1,17
         sumWt= sumWt + Wt(i)
 10   CONTINUE

      RETURN
      END
      !Function used to sum weighted values of t^0
      !*****************************************************************


      !*****************************************************************
      DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION sum2(sumWt2,Wt2)
      IMPLICIT NONE
      INTEGER i,t2(17)
      DOUBLE PRECISION sumWt2,Wt2(17),eCt(17),W(17)

      W(i)= 1/((eCt(i))**2)

      DO i= 1,17,1

      Wt2(i)= W(i)*t2(i)
      END DO


      SumWt2= 0.0
      DO 10 i=1,17
         sumWt2= sumWt2 + Wt2(i)
 10   CONTINUE

      RETURN
      END
      !Function used to sum weighted values of t^0
      !*****************************************************************
```

No clue why it keeps doing this.

Comment: Hi @user3228501! Try to keep your questions concise and to the point on SO, it keeps it useful for everybody! You might consider re-visiting your last paragraph, as I'm having trouble working out what you mean.

Comment: Which bit's got you? I need this chunk of code to add together each value in a one dimensional array that contains seventeen values. But, the code either gives me a ridiculously off value or won't compile when I try to rearrange things.

Comment: For starters while *"The chunk of program I'm working on at the associated data file."* definately contains English words, I'm convinced they're not meant to work in that order.

Comment: lol yeah that was meant to be and. It's been edited, let me know if it needs any more changes :)

Comment: There is no good reason for shackling yourself to FORTRAN77, it's 2014 and there have been 4 revisions to the language standard since that one.  The Fortran 90 revision introduced the `sum` function which does exactly what you want. Use it.

Comment: Here's my good reason- nuclear reactors still use fortran77 for their code, and that's what we're taught to use.
So yeah. I could use the much better fortran90 and get a zero on my assignment, or I can struggle on til it works in 77 and get a mark for it. Nobody uses a language this crappy by choice :p

Answer (score 2):

Why are you calling functions ?  You are writing statements such as

```
CALL sum2(sumWt2,Wt2)
```

but `sum2` is declared as

```
DOUBLE PRECISION FUNCTION sum2(sumWt2,Wt2)
```

`CALL` is properly applied only to subroutines. If you don't understand the difference between subroutines and functions go back to your textbook or other favourite tutorial resource and re-read the relevant sections. In Fortran a function returns a value and is typically used on the rhs of an assignment such as

```
mysum = sum2(values)
```

In addition to this confusion you are declaring `sum2` to be of type `REAL` in the opening of the program, then later defining a `double precision` function of the same name.  I suspect that this inconsistency may be the immediate cause of the error message you report.

Right now it looks to me as if you are trying to write a program beyond your current capabilities.  Forget about it until you can write, and call, either a function (this is what I would advise) or a subroutine to return the sum of a rank 1 array of values. In other words write a FORTRAN77 function to implement the forbidden fruit of Fortran 90's `sum` intrinsic.

And if you are editing your question again make sure that:

- all the code is formatted as code, right now there are stray statements formatted as text;
- drop the `continue` statements, replace them with `end do`;
- delete all the excess whitespace and lines of asterisks, they're not helping us to read and understand your code;
- use indentation to make the structure of your code clear to you and to us; if you feel constrained by the terms of your assignment to turn in fixed-format source then do so, but show us indented code.

Comment: Because as it is, I'm learning this as I go. I don't have some fabled resource I can keep running back to; the "notes" we were given are less than useless, so all I can do is run to the internet and, when searching fails, put myself at the mercy of those who know more.
Ah that's the result of me messing around trying to wobble my way around the error. Forgot to change it back, it's been a long day.

Comment: lol yeah I could've told you that! But there's no time for messing around, this is an assignment we've been given and I'm learning it the hard way. As it is we just haven't used the language enough for everything to be etched into permanent memory, so it's a case of picking up the pieces and trying to remember what it all means. Though I know for sure I've never had to use a Function before in the course.

Anyway, thanks for the tips and I'll give it a run-through now.

Comment: I've made the corrections and, whilst it compiles without error, the program crashes on execution. 11:22 is too late at night for this when I have labs in the morning, this will have to wait for further attention til tomorrow evening.

Comment: FORTRAN subroutines and functions don't inherit variables from "above" or globally. They are completely separate compilations, so, for example, in sum1, eCt() will be a _local_ variable with no existing values that you can count on. Also, the assignment to W(i) is outside the Do-loop. You might as well merge the two Do-loops into one while you're at it.

Comment: Yeah I ended up merging the do loops and, after rereading the assignment, found that apparently it's just a least-mean-squares fit, not a weighted one! So I successfully wasted most of a day, ah well. No need for functions or subroutines at this juncture, though I thankyou for the instruction on them. I have another question regarding arrays and matrix manipulation but I'll start a fresh page for that.

Answer (score 0):

What kind of error message(s) are you getting? Is the compiler accepting the multiline statement in the DO 10 "loop" (no column 6 continuation mark needed?), and what are you doing there anyway? I would think you would simply stick a `sumWt0 = sumWt0 + Wt0(i)` in the 1..17 loop above (I assume it's a typo that you're trying to work with sumWt0(*) when it's a scalar).

```
PROGRAM test

IMPLICIT NONE
INTEGER i,t0
REAL t(17),Ct(17),eCt(17),W(17),Wt0(17),sumWt0,sum0

OPEN(21, FILE='data.txt', STATUS='OLD')
DO i=1,17
  READ (21,*)t(i),Ct(i),eCt(i)
END DO
CLOSE(21)

SumWt0 = 0.0
DO i= 1,17
  t0= 1            ' What is the purpose of this?

  Wt0(i)=W(i)*t0
  SumWt0 = SumWt0 + Wt0(i)

END DO


WRITE(*,*) 'sumWt0=', sumWt0

STOP
END
```

Comment: A mix, quite a few unclassified statements. I'd forgotten how much of a mess the code had gotten! Been at this for probably three hours now.
I'll attach my main program code since I haven't been messing with it.
Yeah I did initially plan to use functions to do the summations, since there's three of them and they'd need repeating after each shi-squared calculation. But Force2.0 would have none of it. 
The current DO 10 loop is the result of frustration! lol in an attempt to get it to read in the values from the array at all I just tried the long way. You can tell I'm not well practised at this.

Comment: EDIT: t0=1 is because t0, or t^0, is always 1. The DO 10 i=1,17 is a remnant from where I thought simply dropping that above sumWt0(i)= SumWt0(i)+Wt0(i) would get it to cycle through the array.E

EDIT: Though shouldn't the sumWt0 on the LHS be scalar? It's only one value.

Comment: I've edited the original post "test" code to its current, neater state. It compiles, but I get an answer of 8.67663508E+33. That's......a bit different to what my calculator gives, lol

Comment: SumWt0 appears to be intended as a _scalar_. Why in the world do you insist on subscripting it? Anyway, the first thing I'd do is print out the values you've read in (t(i), Ct(i), and eCt(i)) and make sure they hold expected values and weren't misread. Then, where does W(i) come from? I don't see it read in or calculated.

Comment: Perhaps because I'm still learning and am not some coding master like so many on here apparently are? But yes sumWt0 is a scalar, it was probably a typo. I'd been working on this code since 9am this morning without stop, so you'll have to forgive a few silly mistakes. I've removed all old code and got everything working, except calling up subroutines into the main program.